# Recover text from PDF file when normal methods fail

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, text-extraction

I have a few hundred PDF files from which I need to extract sections of text. For many, *pdftotext* works fine, but for others, it misses large sections of text. If I open the PDF in Acrobat and select that text by hand and copy/paste into emacs and then view the file without an encoding, I get stuff like this:

```
 Husband \364\200\200\272\364\200\201\213\364 etc.
```

How can I extract the text correctly?

I should mention that I've tried saving as text from Acrobat; also tried applying Acrobat's Document=>OCR feature before copying.

Comment: Have you read all links in **Related** column on the right? To get the scale of the problem and lack of general universal solution? Maybe if you post a sample, someone might suggest solution for your special case. And, for OCR to work, you should have rasterized the file first.

Comment: Thanks @VadimR those are helpful suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Why not convert the PDF to doc or txt first? See the guide:
http://www.aolor.com/pdf-converter/user-guide.html